# In Excel find and return next value that meets the criteria

Tags: excel, return

Have a seemingly simple question that I just don’t know how to fix. These are the excel columns:

```
PointID     number         result 
  **1       1               
    2       1 #end       resultA (3)**
    3       0
    4       0
  **5       1 #start     
    6       1            
    7       1 #end       resultB (2)**
    8       0
    9       1 #start     
    10      1 #end           
    11      0
```

# is the comment sign. 
 bewtween **  ** is highlight

The key is to find a value in ‘number’ column with current value being 1 and next one being 0 (call it end point), and then look for next value in same column with current value being 1 and previous one being 0 (call start point). Between each start point and end point is a short line.

Then in ‘result’ column (can go to any row), calculate a result of function based on existing values (just name it functionA ) and when the calculated result resultA reaches a threshold value 3, I will highlight all the values involved in these two lines and remove them later on. As seen in the data. resultA is calculated using the value of points (ID2 and ID5) in ‘number ’ column, and it reaches the threshold , so all points in these two lines are highlighted in bold font. resultB doesn’t reach the threshold, so points in line3 are not highlighted. I cannot think of how to write function that fill in the column ‘result’ . Any idea?[image]

Now the question has simplified: the H column is my result  ! And what i need to do is just find the H cell that is small than 100 (the cell highlighted is 48 so it meets criteria), and highlight all data that have consecutive 1 values in K column as 1,1,1,... and closest to the current row. as being highlighted in the image. This selection is the final step.

to clarify:

H column in worksheet corresponds to result column in the first excel dataset. Now just look 
at the worksheet.

this row 13 (with H value of 48.9) is where a end point is in--from K column you can see a series of 1.. and that tells you where is end and starting point of each list made of 1.

so 48.09 on H13 is calculated using the G13 and G15, which are the G column value of end point of current list and starting point of next list. so K13=function(G13,G15)

what needs to do is, if this value in H < 100, then find all the points in these two lists and select (first list goes up from current end point until 1 disappears in the K column, and second list goes down from next starting point until 1 disappears in K column).

as in sheet, since 48<100, I simply select all the points in previous list of 1 (that is from row 6-13), and points in next list (that is from row 14 to 22) and highlight them in red.

Hope the problem is understanble now, it is kinda hard to describe but really should be simple problem. Dont know if excel can handle this.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this question, nor the answer below. First problem, the first sentence says "Here are the excel columns" followed by a rather large and cryptic text table, followed later by an apparently unrelated image of an Excel sheet. Your description of the "result" function and related actions taken based on its value is also hard to follow. Please clarify the question.

Comment: just did. see the edits

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that it took me a while to even comprehend how you were arriving at the numbers within your *results* column but I think I have a formula based solution.

[image: Formatted aggregate results]

I had to split off the *#start* and *#end* labels in order to treat the numbers in column B as actual numbers. The formula in D2 is,

`=IF(AND($B2=1,$B3=0),TEXT(IFERROR(MATCH(1, $B3:$B$99,0),COUNT($B2:$B$98)),"\r\e\s\u\l\t\"&CHAR(64+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(LEN($D$1:$D1))))&"\(0\)\*\*"),"")`

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: the way I arrive at the result is based on a calculation formula so is another issue. I dont understand your formula, but to simplify it I can just output the value of next starting point to the E column of current point. then I will start from there. Then e.g for point 3 I can use B3 and E3 to get the result

Comment: @widget - You shouldn't have any trouble pulling out the `MATCH` portion of that code that actually returns the number you are looking for. I found that I needed to compensate for the open ended bottom of your data table with `IFERROR` and `COUNT` in order to get a correct (?) result for the last return.

Comment: Hi actually I just output the correct value, and also calculated the result using the function. i used index, and match function, it's kinda complicated. anyway, what's left is just to highlight all the points that have a result which meets the criteria (>3). I am still trying to figure out this one